# Gitlab CICD pipeline not giving output for aws command

Tags: bash, gitlab-ci, aws-cli

[edit]

I'm trying to add artifacts to s3 for different versions of my repo: 1.0.0, 1.0.1, etc. So I need to check if s3://artifacts/1.0.0/ exists. For that I'm using `aws s3 ls` and then checking if `$? == 0`. This check is to ensure I'm not overwriting a version of the code that already exists, to force version increments by the developer.
Below is basically the bash file that just performs the check. (There are other files to perform uploading `aws s3 cp` that I omit).

```bash
#!/bin/bash
version=1.0.0 # hardcoded for now
url=s3://artifacts/$version
aws s3 ls $url
if [[ $? == 0 ]]; 
then 
    echo "Version $version already exists. Exiting ..."
    exit 1
else 
    echo "Version $version does not exist. Continuing ..."; 
fi
```

On windows and mac, the `echo` statements execute, but not in the docker image in Gitlab's CICD pipeline, which echo's nothing and just exits. I would like something meaningful to be printed on the terminal for future users.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: the command failed (exit code 1), ref https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/return-codes.html#aws-cli-return-codes - what is your specific question? have you tried to add the `--debug` switch to obtain more information? ref https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/ls.html#global-options

Comment: Can you show your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file? You could also try `echo "..." > /dev/stderr` in case something is capturing stdout or adding the debug flag `-x` to bash.

Comment: Also: `if ! aws s3 ls "$url"; then echo "this failed (exit code non-zero)"; else echo "listing listing listing"; fi` if it helps to keep it more dense ($? contains the exit code of the last command)